# FormClose how can make my App Extract this Folder Auto

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

need my App when the Form Close It Create this Folder Auto and every time 
this form open and close it's update the files Auto.

```
+'Userinfo\'+BuddyName+'Archive\'+BuddyName+');
```

---

```
Procedure TPMWindow.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
Begin
  button1.click;
memo1.Lines.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Userinfo\'+BuddyName+'Archive\'+BuddyName+''+BuddyName+'.html');
```

Comment: What's stopping you doing this?

Comment: i need to know the comment about how to do my App extract this path auto  and update auto too this form work to save Privacy Massage Archive

Comment: the save action it's Already Work but must be create the folder by my self i need the app create this path  +'Userinfo\'+BuddyName+'Archive\'+BuddyName+')  Automatic  i need to know how to type this .

Comment: What we don't know is what your problem is. You already have code that saves the content of your memo control to a file. You have not told us what the problem is. You have not asked a question.

Comment: I am wondering if 'ForceDirectories();' is the answer to your question

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ForceDirectories` to create the entire folder tree, and then write the file to there:

```
procedure TPMWindow.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var
  FolderPath: string;
begin
  FolderPath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'UserInfo\' +
                   BuddyName + 'Archive\';
  if ForceDirectories(FolderPath) then
    // Your filename makes no sense to me, but typing it as you wrote it
    Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile(FolderPath + BuddyName + BuddyName + '.html');
end;
```

If you're using a more recent version of Delphi that includes `IOUtils`, you should use `TPath.Combine` to build the `FolderPath`, and `TDirectory.CreateDirectory` in place of `ForceDirectories` instead.

Comment: Yes Thnks So much It's Working ... THis the `ForceDirectories`

Comment: The newer, device-independent way is to use TDirectory.CreateDirectory. "Use CreateDirectory to create a new directory at the given path. If the directories given in the path do not yet exist, CreateDirectory attempts to create them."

Comment: @Ron: Yes, I'm aware. I'm also aware that this question is specifically tagged Delphi 7. :-) I added a paragraph to include the IOUtils info for future reference. Thanks.